# SVN Log stop on previous copy

Tags: bash, svn

If I create a branch from trunk then do some commits I can see the branch commits nicely with

```
svn log --stop-on-copy .
```

However, sometimes I have created a branch from a branch and want to see the log back to the previous branch creation.

I pretty sure that there is no `svn log --stop-on-previous-copy`

The manual way to do it is to find the branch it was created from then do log from the pegged revision

```
svn log --stop-on-copy http://my.svn.server/repo/branches/branch@1234
```

How can I wrap this up in a way that allows me to do it with one command?

EDIT: There is an outstanding feature request for this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-2518 in the meantime we will have to work out how to script it.